# All imports in import declaration are unused. Components imported from reactstrap cannot be recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to use the reactstrap dependency in my web application but all imports cannot be recognized.

I have tried re-installing and checked the source folder for the dependencies and they seemed alright. I'm using the MERN stack and am running both servers from the client(react, port 3000) and server side (port 5000).

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import {
 Collapse,
 Navbar,
 NavbarToggler,
 NavbarBrand,
 Nav,
 NavItem,
 NavLink,
 Container
} from "reactstrap";
```

The import {...,...,...} from "reactstrap" has become light colored in the editor and I got a message saying that all imports in the declaration are unused.

Below is the information from the package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
  "jquery": "^3.4.1",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
  "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
  "react-transition-group": "^4.1.0",
  "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
  "typescript": "^3.5.1",
  "uuid": "^3.3.2"
   },
  "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
   "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
   "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
   },
   "browserslist": {
   "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
     ],
     "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
      ]
     } 
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using them in the component? That message just means that you're not using the components you have imported. You can ignore that message for now

Comment: Say you imported Component from React, but you didn't actually create the component? You'll get the same message. The idea is, whatever dependency you import, use it. Otherwise, why import them?

Comment: IDE is assisting you to remove unnecessary imports for potential tree shaking purpose. If you are still in development you can ignore the warning and it will go away as you tend to use those components.

Answer (score -2):

That is just your editor telling you that the components you've imported aren't actually being used in the file. Try using them in your code and the warning will go away.

Comment: You dont 'use' the React import.